# Как передать позицию списка внутри списка

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

У меня есть `RecyclerView1` в котором находиться другой `RecyclerView2` в горизонтальном положении, я скролю `RecyclerView2` после чего нажимаю на `item` внутри этого `RecyclerView2` и у меня происходит `replace fragment` после чего я нажимаю `onBackpressed` и по возвращению назад мой `RecyclerView2` не сохраняет позицию пролистанного.

Важно, `RecyclerView1` я создаю внутри приложения, а `RecyclerView2` это `Firestore`

Раньше когда я создавал список `RecyclerView2` в самом фрагмент, то при `replace fragment` мой список сохранял позицию пролистанного, делал я это с помощью этой строки:
`Objects.requireNonNull(holder.rv_item_block.getAdapter()).setStateRestorationPolicy(StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY);`

Но теперь когда `RecyclerView1` в котором находиться `RecyclerView2`, то внутренний список, то есть `RecyclerView2`, позицию не сохраняет, у меня есть предположение почему так происходит, скорее всего из-за того что фрагмент создаёт сначала первый список а потом второй, позиция скажем так аннулируется и приходиться листать заново.

Я знаю что я скорее всего не совсем понятно изложил свою мысль, попытался объяснить как мог.

Я попробовал в `Adapter1` 1го `RecyclerView1`, внутри которого находиться `RecyclerView2`, добавить эту строку:
`holder.rv_item_block.post(() -> holder.rv_item_block.setScrollX(holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()));`
Но это не помогло список всё равно не возвращается в нужную позицию.

Также я думал просто сохранять позицию пролистанного в `Shared preferences` но в таком случае, после нажатия `onBackpressed` он будет применяться на все внутренние `RecyclerView2`.

Прикрепляю гиф с тем как это выглядит на практике.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы `RecyclerView2` сохранял позицию пролистанного после `replace fragment`.

Теперь код

Мой Фрагмент в котором находиться `RecyclerView1`

```
public class FragmentTestRec extends Fragment {

    public static FragmentTestRec newInstance() {
        return new FragmentTestRec();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_rec, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ImageView iv_back_test = requireView().findViewById(R.id.iv_back_test);
        iv_back_test.setOnClickListener(v -> requireActivity().onBackPressed());

        RecyclerView rv_test_1 = requireView().findViewById(R.id.rv_test_1);

        rv_test_1.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv_test_1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        ArrayList<ItemBlock> itemBlock = new ArrayList<>();
        itemBlock.add(new ItemBlock(R.string.Test_1, "TurnKeyAll"));
        AdapterTestRec adapterBlock = new AdapterTestRec(itemBlock, getContext());
        rv_test_1.setAdapter(adapterBlock);
    }
}
```

`Adapter` for `RecyclerView1`

```
public class AdapterTestRec extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTestRec.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ItemBlock> itemTestRvs;
    static Context context;

    public AdapterTestRec(List<ItemBlock> itemTestRvs, Context context) {
        this.itemTestRvs = itemTestRvs;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterTestRec.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_block, parent, false);
        return new AdapterTestRec.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterTestRec.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ItemBlock Item = itemTestRvs.get(position);

        holder.tv_item_block.setText(Item.getName());

        holder.cv_item_block.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            ((MainActivity) context).showFragment(FragmentListWide.newInstance());

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("tv_list", String.valueOf(Item.getName()));
            bundle.putString("rv_list", String.valueOf(Item.getRvFilter()));

            MainActivity.curFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        });

        FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Search));
        AdapterTestRecSnap adapterWideSnap;

        Query query = collectionReference.orderBy(Item.getRvFilter(), Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemSearch> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ItemSearch>()
                .setQuery(query, ItemSearch.class).build();

        adapterWideSnap = new AdapterTestRecSnap(firestoreRecyclerOptions, context);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager RLM_tasks_all = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        SnapHelper snapHelper = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(holder.rv_item_block);
        holder.rv_item_block.setHasFixedSize(false);
        holder.rv_item_block.setLayoutManager(RLM_tasks_all);
        holder.rv_item_block.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        holder.rv_item_block.setAdapter(adapterWideSnap);
        adapterWideSnap.startListening();
        Objects.requireNonNull(holder.rv_item_block.getAdapter()).setStateRestorationPolicy(StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemTestRvs.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_item_block;
        private RecyclerView rv_item_block;
        private CardView cv_item_block;
        private ConstraintLayout cl_item_block;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_item_block = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_block);
            rv_item_block = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_item_block);
            cv_item_block = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_block);
            cl_item_block = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cl_item_block);
        }
    }
}
```

А это Адаптер2 для самого списка то есть `RecyclerView2`

```
public class AdapterTestRecSnap extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ItemSearch, AdapterTestRecSnap.ViewHolder> {

    public Context context;

    public AdapterTestRecSnap(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ItemSearch> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ItemSearch model) {

        holder.cv_item_wide.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            Glide.with(context).load(model.getSearchBackground()).transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()).into(holder.iv1_item_wide);

            FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            DocumentReference documentReference2 = firebaseFirestore.collection(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Information)).document(model.getid());
            documentReference2.get().addOnCompleteListener(task ->
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    ((MainActivity) context).showFragment(FragmentKeysBlanc.newInstance());

                    MainActivity.curFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_wide_snap, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv_item_wide;
        ImageView iv1_item_wide;
        ImageView iv2_item_wide;
        TextView tv1_item_wide;
        TextView tv2_item_wide;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv_item_wide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_item_wide);
            iv1_item_wide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv1_item_wide);
            iv2_item_wide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv2_item_wide);
            tv1_item_wide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1_item_wide);
            tv2_item_wide = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2_item_wide);
        }
    }
}
```